# OkHttp3 - How to build an httpUrl using a hostname host?

Tags: android, network-programming, okhttp, hostname

I have an OpenShift application which serves as my Application server.

I have the following function:

```
 public static HttpUrl.Builder getBaseHttpUrlBuilder(String path) {
        return new HttpUrl.Builder()
                .scheme("http")
                .host(SERVER_HOST)
                .port(SERVER_PORT)
                .addPathSegment(path);
    }
```

Where `SERVER_HOST = "http://my-server.1d35.starter-us-east-1.openshiftapps.com"` .

When I run the server locally, i.e. `SERVER_HOST = "127.0.0.1"` it working good.

No I'm getting the following exception:

```
10-08 19:48:22.843 12923-13932/com.nprogramming.android.couponsapp E/LoginUtils: Error in Login: unexpected host: http://my-server.1d35.starter-us-east-1.openshiftapps.com
10-08 19:48:22.843 12923-13932/com.nprogramming.android.couponsapp W/System.err: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: unexpected host: http://my-server.1d35.starter-us-east-1.openshiftapps.com
10-08 19:48:22.844 12923-13932/com.nprogramming.android.couponsapp W/System.err:     at okhttp3.HttpUrl$Builder.host(HttpUrl.java:1027)
        at com.nprogramming.android.couponsapp.Utils.LoginUtils.login(LoginUtils.java:65)
        at com.nprogramming.android.couponsapp.Activities.LoginActivity$LoginTask.loadInBackground(LoginActivity.java:178)
        at com.nprogramming.android.couponsapp.Activities.LoginActivity$LoginTask.loadInBackground(LoginActivity.java:166)
        at android.support.v4.content.AsyncTaskLoader.onLoadInBackground(AsyncTaskLoader.java:306)
        at android.support.v4.content.AsyncTaskLoader$LoadTask.doInBackground(AsyncTaskLoader.java:59)
        at android.support.v4.content.AsyncTaskLoader$LoadTask.doInBackground(AsyncTaskLoader.java:47)
        at android.support.v4.content.ModernAsyncTask$2.call(ModernAsyncTask.java:138)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
```

How Do I build an OkHttp url using a hostname?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: did you try baseUrl instead ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SERVER_HOST = "my-server.1d35.starter-us-east-1.openshiftapps.com"
```

Comment: Thank you great lady :)